# How can I fix my website's display problems on old Internet Explorer versions?

Tags: joomla-2.5, module-display

I'm not a developer by any means, so I'm not sure I'll be able to phrase this in a technical way, but I'm facing a lot of problems with how my new Joomla website is rendered on old versions of IE.

The website is [www.eslrok.com](http://www.eslrok.com) (a jobs/recruiting website for English teachers in Korea).

It's really important that the website display correctly on the older versions of IE (6 through 9), but, having accessed the site from computers using older browsers and having seen the site on sites like Browsera.com, I can see that the browser stretches the component on the front page and pushes all of the left-side modules underneath it. It's a mess.

I've read so many things about IE display problems and how to fix them, all of them pointing to different solutions.

What I can't do is ask the user to turn on compatibility mode, it needs to render correctly on load. I installed a plugin that alerts users to the fact that their browser is outdated, but I'd prefer to have the page look decent instead, and not force them to make an annoying upgrade (although they probably should, but it's not my business to tell them this).

Does anybody have any experience with this? Or perhaps there's a sneaky fix that someone has heard about?

Comment: You are using the JSN Metro Pro template, have you contacted their support forum? Make sure you are using an up to date version of the framework. It's gonna be a css issue I'd presume.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny_S, I'll ask them for their ideas on this, they'll probably have heard similar things from other users of that template. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I'm assuming you're using a responsive template here which means it will scale down elements using CSS3 media queries which are not supported on older browsers.

There are 2 things you need to do:

1. When viewing your site in IE, make sure it's not in **Quirks mode**. To double check, simply press <kbd>F12</kbd>, check the document mode and make sure it's set to **Standard**.
2. Make sure your `<head>` contains `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

You also have an Javascript errors coming from **responsivescrollingtables.min.js** which is also causing problems for **respond.js** and preventing it from working.

Also I don't get this really. You would like to support older browsers, however you have an upgrade message appear when viewing the browser in IE8

Comment: Thank you, Lodder, and thanks for pointing out the respond.js problems. I'll have my developer take a look at that. As for the upgrade message, that was a temporary fix that I hoped would be enough, but having read more into the problems with IE and display issues, a few articles pointed out that not all users will be browsing from home, and having to upgrade a browser on a work computer can be thought of as an unecessary annoyance. I'd much rather fix the problems and not have the message displayed. Again, thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: @BenGoldie - You're welcome. I'll admit, catering for older IE versions can be a hard job sometimes. Especially when using a lot of Javascript. A good thing to do is if you ever use a javascript/jquery plugin of some sort, heck the developer site and make sure it supports older browser cause if it doesn't it will cause problems with other scripts ;)